# Evaluate the integral by U Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I can solve this by partial fractions but can someone solve it by only and only u substitution?

$$\int\frac{x^{2}}{(x+1)^{3}}dx$$

Thanks,

Edit:

this is what I did:
$x=u-1 => \int\frac{(u-1)^{2}}{(u)^{3}}du = \int\frac{u^2-2u+1}{(u)^{3}}du = \int\frac{u-2}{(u)^{2}}du + \int\frac{1}{(u)^{3}}du$ but I did not get anywhere.

Comment: Hint: Let $u = x + 1$, so that $x = u - 1$.

Comment: tried but I got a wrong result. Perhaps I did something wrong there.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include what you tried? It might just be a slight calculation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$∫\dfrac{x^2}{(x+1)^3}dx$$
Let u=x+1
$$∫\dfrac{(u-1)^2}{(u)^3}du$$
$$∫\dfrac{u^2-2u+1}{(u)^3}du$$
$$∫\dfrac{1}{u}-\dfrac{2}{u^2}+\dfrac{1}{u^3}du$$

I think you can take over from there. Integrate and back substitude u=x+1

NB: $$∫\dfrac{1}{u}du=ln(|u|)+c$$